# What to know of implementation besides contract?

Tags: oop, architecture, solid-principles

Both L and D in SOLID encourage us to program against contracts, not actual implementations. But does that mean an interface consumer should not know the implementation, or just that he should not rely on implementation doing something not stated in a contract explicitly?

I mean, we can have a method to create a new NumericParameter in DB, but its interface only says that! It does not say that NumericParameter is actually an inherited entity spanning over 2 tables, or that the method also creates one more related entity to save some more data about the created entity. Those are implementation details.

It's very clear why one should not depend on implementation doing something. But maybe it's justifiable to depend on implementation *NOT* doing something (even if it's not stated in a contract?) Otherwise, how are you going to modify your code at all? Any time you add some activity, it can come to conflict with something that is happening in some of the other methods and services you call. Like, you read a DB row "for update", then call foo() and then write a row back with some modifications, but it appears that foo() already made some changes to the same row - in this very transaction - and they will be overwritten.

On the other hand, implementation can be changed. If some consumer depends on it NOT doing something, then at some moment that dependency may break. Meaning, not only have we to examine what code is called from the code being edited, but also possible callers of the code. Everything that may be happening in any transaction triggering this code, we must know in details.

Somehow I think that is a smell, but how do you live without it? I usually  try to ignore implementation details, but on multiple occasions that ended up in some conflicts.

Comment: What do you mean by *doing something not stated in a contract*? Something with the data it receives? Something with the outside world? With its caller? In the `foo()` example, what would we expect the dependency NOT to do?

Comment: A more recent example. One part of logic deletes an entity A; some other part modifies a B which is referenced by A. Due to the nature of JPA API, if the referenced entity contains a collection of all entities referring to it, this collection (cached, once read from DB) has to remain coherent with the actual entities which were also cached in this transaction. Thus, despite those two parts of logic not being naturally conflicting, deleting the entity A and then persisting a current state of B (which now lost coherency because it still contains reference to A) will introduce a conflict.

Comment: This example shows us this: any code modifying some B has to rely on the other code called by it to NOT delete any A's. If it cannot rely on it, then its author cannot be sure he does not introduce a conflict by writing this code.

Comment: Or, simpler yet, any code reading some entity from DB has to rely that no other service it executes attempts to delete that entity from DB (which may come as "internal details of implementation" of that latter service).

Comment: Surely it is up to the implementor of B what to do in this situation. Either it raises an error or automatically fixes the conflict. I don&#39;t see how this affects the contract of B. Am I missing the point of your example?

Comment: Implementor of B? Who's that? B is just an entity here, not an interface/service. Besides, my point is: to be able to fix a conflict one has to expect a conflict (hence know what code can be executed in this transaction that may lead to conflict), or, alternatively, to be able to prevent a conflict one has also to know exactly what can happen and what cannot.

Comment: I concur with @the4amigo_uk. Your premise is that you should be able to count on a dependency to *not* do something. But you're not JPA's dependency - they cannot count on your code not deleting any `A`'s. *They* are the ones exposing a contract, you aren't.

Comment: I see. You say that technically JPA is proposing a contract, and if I am using it then I have to respect it? It's OK. But how would I respect it? I would have to know what does every part of my code do. From there I will have two options: 1) "this one deletes the entity, then that one has to reflect this deletion in some other entity's references" - i.e. relying on particular actions made, 2) "this one surely does not delete the entity, hence that one does not need to defend from it" - i.e. relying on NOT doing a bad thing.

Comment: ...So I asked whether it will be more correct to behave as in pt. 2 and rely on NOT doing something. Granted, it would be even better to not having to have complete knowledge at all, but I could not understand how to be prepared to conflict then. Now I believe the4thamigo_uk is close to an answer.

Comment: You misunderstood me. JPA, not you, has to respect their contract. But concurrent access problems have nothing to do with the contract or the way JPA is implemented internally. They have to do with what you, the client, do with JPA, and when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, let me summarise the gathered wisdom.

1) Usually all significant effects of a method are either part of its contract (or should be), or are dictated by the environment (like it's with JPA's deletion having interference with JPA's modification some other entity). If it's the former, then the contract tell us what to expect, and if it's the latter, the developer is supposed to know the effect of environment he himself defined. So, in both cases he should be aware of possible conflicts *without* knowing implementation. A properly designed method can hardly cause some major effect totally unrelated to its contract and to environment/settings/etc., or at least no example of that comes to my mind or was mentioned by anyone else here. Unless, of course, that method is used by someone who knows it far too intimately and depends on its implementation; but in this case I of course have to know the implementation anyway and my question is not applicable.

2) In my question I mentioned implementation details like "inherited entity spanning over several tables" and "creates one more entity". Well, problems specific for JPA inheritance are part of environment; creating extra entities should either be part of contract (if the entity is referred by someone else) or not cause any interference (if it's strictly private thing), or be part of environment if it's product of some "aspect" introduced by configuration on top original method's logic.

Thus, the answer to my original question is "no need to know implementation details" (unless you have to work with tightly coupled classes), and "given properly defined contracts and properly designed methods, you can live without that because you should know everything you need from contracts and environment".

Answer (score 0):

This is on the fringe of "opinionated", but I think the factual answer to

> he should not rely on implementation doing something not stated in a contract explicitly?

should be **yes - exactly**. And that is the the **core** element here. It is pretty common that the person writing up the interface will write at least one implementation as well. And probably have that implementation already designed a bit (at least in the back of your mind) when writing down the interface. So "knowing about the implementation" is something that you most often can't avoid in the real world. So better focus on the second part of your statement.

Beyond that: when you find the contract to be *ambiguous* then do not spend your time worrying about different interpretations. Rather use your energy to **clarify** the contract to a degree that it becomes "clear enough" what the implementation is supposed to do or not do.

Comment: Ok, and what would be your answer to "maybe it's justifiable to depend on implementation NOT doing something"? I described a problem above...

Answer (score 0):

I think the key to SOLID is that you should aim to use *all*  the principles, where possible, not just pick one or two in isolation. The example you give with foo(), is a problem because two areas of your code deal with the same database record. My interpretation is that this is a violation of the S in SOLID.

Comment: With foo(), I agree with your reasoning, but not quite: there may be reasons for two services to touch the same record. For one, it may just be a coincidence that they ended up working with the same record: one service was working with X and another was looking up some Y by some conditions, and found Y=X.

Comment: Still, because you have a point, I provided another example in responses to guillaume31: there, no database entity is accessed by both services in single transaction, but still the conflict is provoked by the underlaying framework which misinterprets the situation. At the level of design everything is OK, then. But to know of the problem, I have to know that the called service does removal, and even *how* JPA will implement that removal.

Comment: Also, I believe S does not require us to have only one *class* responsible for some feature. It's the other way around: S requires a class to be responsible for one *feature*; that does not mean some other class cannot participate in implementing that same feature. Including accessing the same row. Or, to depend on same reason for design changes. Also, accessing the row may be not a primary task of a method but just a result of its decomposition.

Comment: Let's even say OK we split foo() method into parts, according to the decomposition I just mentioned above. One part does something, the other part is moved to yet another function bar() - yes, single responsibility - and it deletes an entity. Even in this case the initial caller who calls foo() still has to be aware that foo() calls bar() in its turn, otherwise he is unprepared for the conflict.

Comment: bar() should gracefully handle this situation by resolving the conflict, or by returning an error (providing the contract allows for errors).

Comment: Also, I do think that the wording of the SRP is confusing and quite ill-defined and also pretty fluid (e.g. first para of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). SOLID is not a legal document, and nor does it tell us how to architect our system, It is a set of guidelines to help us think about the maintainability of the software that we write, in particular the control of change and dependencies.

Comment: Since, you are proposing two have two modules responsible for the same functionality, the Common Closure Principle is probably more appropriate, which would tell you to bind them together in a component. Regardless, these two modules are cohesive and tightly coupled, and they should be designed to be compatible.

Comment: "bar() should gracefully handle this situation" - ok so you suggest that not a caller should expect a conflict, but a callee. It's the same thing as far as my initial question is concerned: when I write a callee I have to contemplate all possible conflicts which can occur with other parts of my app, to avoid them. And to do that, I will have to know all the actions that can occur in other parts of code in the same transaction. Right? Otherwise, without knowing the nature of conflict, one cannot probably avoid it or gracefully handle it.

Comment: "Regardless, these two modules are cohesive and tightly coupled, and they should be designed to be compatible." - this starts to sound like a plan. So, instead of ensuring compatibility of all my code involved in a transaction, I will only have to ensure compatibility between code which I know is tightly coupled. So, in my example with JPA, I would know that the conflict is coming, because I would examine compatibility between the calling code and the called code (their being coupled).

Comment: But, there's still a problem. Two classes are highly coupled when I design them so, that's OK. But they also can be tightly coupled without me knowing it (like, via JPA behavior). Now, without me knowing what JPA actions does one part of my code perform, I cannot see if my other code is coupled with it. Thus again, to protect against conflicts I have to know coupling and to know coupling I have to know everything that can happen. Don't you think so?

Answer (score 0):

> But does that mean an interface consumer should not know the
>   implementation, or just that he should not rely on implementation
>   doing something not stated in a contract explicitly?

The former. However could the dependency keep itself from touching external stuff that they're not even aware the client cares about? A contract is not so much about saying "don't move my cheese" but rather "give me back something with the shape I expect, no matter which way you do it".

The only other answer I see is to use pure (side-effect free) functions, but we're not really in the realm of OOP any more.

Comment: "However could the dependency keep itself from touching external stuff that they're not even aware the client cares about?" - yes and that's what makes me suggest that maybe I, as an author to the code which at some point executes that dependency, have to know enough of dependency's implementation to judge whether it's safe to use it in particular circumstances. This way, I can rely on implementation NOT doing anything conflicting with rest of my code. Hence the latter option.

Comment: All examples of problems you brought up are due to shared mutable state and concurrent access by two consumers in **your code**. The concrete implementation of the dependency doesn't matter. Knowing the underlying implementation of the dependency won't change a thing about the presence of competing consumers.

Comment: Knowing an implementation of both consumers would at least let one see they ARE competing! Not knowing consumer internals (the fact that one of them tries to delete the entity - if it's a side effect and not part of contract), one would reasonably decide that another consumer (modifying another entity referring to that one) cannot conflict with the first.

Comment: However since I cannot think of a proper example, I suppose it's OK to assume that usually all significant effects of a method are (or supposed to be) either part of its contract, or are dictated by the environment, like it's with JPA. And if it's the latter, the developer is supposed to know the effect of environment he himself defined. (my JPA example demonstrates the interference effect not stated in a method's contract *but* it's part of JPA contract and JPA is part of environment I myself provided, so I am supposed to expect interference here).